# UISegmentedControll changes height when segment selected

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've set the height of my UISegmentedControl in Storyboard with a constant. When I run the app - it looks fine and how I want it to look. However, as soon as I select a segment (anyone) the UiSegmentedControl changes its height to default one. If I select the current index again a few times, it returns to the height I set it to.

Can someone tell me whats going on here?

Thank you!

**Edit Some code:**

This method is called from `viewDidLoad`

```
    -(void)setupSegmented
{
    self.segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    if ([UIImage instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(imageWithRenderingMode:)]) {

        /* For non Selected Segments */
            self.allInactive = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Segment All"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
            self.auctionInactive = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Segment Auction"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
            self.buyNowInactive = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Segment Buy Now"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
            self.classifiedInactive = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Segment Classified"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

        /*For selected Segments */
            self.allActive = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Segment All Active"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
            self.auctionActive = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Segment Auction Active"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
            self.buyNowActive = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Segment Buy Now Active"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
            self.classifiedActive = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Segment Classified Active"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    }

    [self.segmentedControl setImage:self.allInactive forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [self.segmentedControl setImage:self.auctionInactive forSegmentAtIndex:1];
    [self.segmentedControl setImage:self.buyNowInactive forSegmentAtIndex:2];
    [self.segmentedControl setImage:self.classifiedInactive forSegmentAtIndex:3];

}
```

Thus method is called when I tap a segment:

```
    - (IBAction)segmentedControlSelected:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {

    switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex){

    case 0:
        {
            self.tradeType = @"UNSPECIFIED";
            [self.segmentedControl setImage:self.allActive forSegmentAtIndex:sender.selectedSegmentIndex];
            [self.segmentedControl setImage:self.auctionInactive forSegmentAtIndex:1];
            [self.segmentedControl setImage:self.buyNowInactive forSegmentAtIndex:2];
            [self.segmentedControl setImage:self.classifiedInactive forSegmentAtIndex:3];

            break;
        }
    case 1:
        {
            self.tradeType = @"ENGLISH_AUCTION";
            [self.segmentedControl setImage:self.auctionActive forSegmentAtIndex:sender.selectedSegmentIndex];
            [self.segmentedControl setImage:self.allInactive forSegmentAtIndex:0];
            [self.segmentedControl setImage:self.buyNowInactive forSegmentAtIndex:2];
            [self.segmentedControl setImage:self.classifiedInactive forSegmentAtIndex:3];

            break;
        }
    case 2:
        {
            self.tradeType = @"FIXED_PRICE";
            [self.segmentedControl setImage:self.buyNowActive forSegmentAtIndex:sender.selectedSegmentIndex];
            [self.segmentedControl setImage:self.allInactive forSegmentAtIndex:0];
            [self.segmentedControl setImage:self.auctionInactive forSegmentAtIndex:1];
            [self.segmentedControl setImage:self.classifiedInactive forSegmentAtIndex:3];

            break;
        }
    case 3:
        {
            self.tradeType = @"CLASSIFIED_CONTACT";
            [self.segmentedControl setImage:self.classifiedActive forSegmentAtIndex:sender.selectedSegmentIndex];
            [self.segmentedControl setImage:self.allInactive forSegmentAtIndex:0];
            [self.segmentedControl setImage:self.auctionInactive forSegmentAtIndex:1];
            [self.segmentedControl setImage:self.buyNowInactive forSegmentAtIndex:2];

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that UISegmentedControl have any code (instantiated, etc..) or is it all SB?

Comment: The only code I have for it is setting its selected images. All images are exactly the same size. I'm using Auto Layout and iOS7 SDK.

Comment: Please post the code that touches it...

Comment: Added the only code related to this segmented control. Thanks!

Comment: You need to enforce the height of the segmented control by setting the frame property in the segmentedControlSelected: method

Comment: How would I do that using auto layout? I believe CGRectMake does not work when auto layout is on.

Comment: @Tander. You are right, its hard to setFrame when Autolayout is on! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850871/cgrectmake-is-not-working-with-uiview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution in this SO answer: [Change Height of UISegmentedControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947630/change-height-of-uisegmentedcontrol)

I had to force the new height in `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubViews` as its called every time `UISegmentedControl` is tapped.